# Oh noes... [pc] Trogdor? You there?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Hello citizens of the Super User Ville!

As our website is all about these beloved personal computers, it appears to me that [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) can be applied to almost any question. As so, I don't think that it is useful to have this tag at all; it simply doesn't add any meaning to a question and isn't useful for searching purposes. I also don't think ye can ask a question that is only about [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) as there would always be a more specific tag available for your question.

Oh, can ye help call the mighty Trogdor to burn this tag?

*Trogdor, can thou help us?*

[image]

Comment: And it has [tag:computer] and [tag:computers] as synonyms.  If you arn't asking about computers... well, you should be asking somewhere else ;p

Comment: What would we use as a tag for people intending it to mean "the whole computer"? Sure, it's a site about computer hardware, but what if it's not a question about a main board, or the CPU, but the box with all that's in it? We have `[computer-building]` and `[computer-buying]`, but they're different... Something like `[computer-system]` maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: It just reappeared today — can we have this tag blacklisted? It really doesn't make sense on Super User.

Comment: @slhck the PC tag has been blacklisted from now on

Answer (score 14):

AFAIK, PC originally meant the line of IBM Personal Computers, and then also the compatible devices. This transformed to computers running Microsoft Windows using an Intel CPU, i.e. "Wintel" computers.

But today, AMD is a strong competitor to Intel, and Windows isn't the only OS, especially not on a site like Super User, where questions of all computer operating systems are available.

I remember software being available for "both PC and Macintosh", and Apple marketing also sees a difference. But really, how big is that difference today, with Macs being based on Intel CPUs, and "Hackintosh" computers being possible?

---

While, using a strict definition, [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) is way more restrictive than e.g. [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware) or [computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer) would be, **the term "PC" in general use has lost most of its meaning**. It needs to go. Let's burn it.